# what is the advantage of using self-join in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

what is the exact purpose of self-join apart from "referencing itself". what exactly we can find by doing this?

from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp) i get it. they want to shows the customers that live in the same city. but doesn't it make more confused? because it shows the exact name twice just with difference "matches". isn't it easier just sorting by the city without using self-join?

Thank you...

Comment: There is no advantage sometimes you simply have no choice - imagine a table which contains parents and children (not in the literal sense) such as employees where boss has employees who have employees etc. Try googling for more examples.

Comment: BTW you shouldn't take the w3schools example too seriously since it is still using outdated implicit joins. And by odd coincidence here's a quesion asked just know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366225/mysql-count-on-precondition

Comment: And take w3schools with a grain of salt. I'm not saying it's not useful, just that the examples are quite simplistic, and some times not really explained the right way. Some of them may even be obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have a table with a foreign key that points to itself, the a self-join is useful to retrieve parent or children rows. You can even produce recursive queries in databases that support them (most of them now).

If there are no foreign keys that point to itself, then it's not possible to perform a self join.

As simple as that.