# MySQL count on precondition?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, subquery

Consider the scheme below

```
id   user   tag    created
1    foo    tag1   2018-09-01
2    foo    tag2   2018-09-01
3    bar    tag1   2018-09-02
4    bar    tag2   2018-09-03
5    kkk    tag2   2018-09-05
6    qqq    tag1   2018-09-12
```

How to find the number of unique user, which after the row 'tag1' there is a 'tag2' followed in future row of that user?

The answer is `2` (foo,bar), based on the above query

Comment: Either a self join, or a group by.

Comment: ID 1 and 2 have same created dates. How do you decide which one is earlier?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation to get the list of users:

```
select user
from t
group by user
having min(case when tag = 'tag1' then created end) < max(case when tag = 'tag2' then created end);
```

To get the number of such users, use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select user
      from t
      group by user
      having min(case when tag = 'tag1' then created end) < max(case when tag = 'tag2' then created end)
     ) u;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub query to find such rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourdata AS t
WHERE tag = 'tag1'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourdata AS x
    WHERE x.user = t.user
    AND x.tag = 'tag2'
    AND (x.created > t.created OR x.id > t.id)
)
```